# Unity3D SplineAnimate Jerky movement

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, spline

There seems to be some erratic SplineAnimate behaviour with certain camera angles.

I've been implementing a racing game that utilizes Unity's SplineAnimates and SplineContainer. There are multiple cameras throughout the race of two types: LookAt, and Follow.

The follow camera simply latches to the racer via child/parent relations or the parent constraint. For profile shots with this follow camera, you can see the SplineAnimates behind the followed racer move sporadically.

I've updated the spline package, I've implemented my own SplineAnimate movement with the container, and I've tried the exact same SplineAnimate movement source with some modifications and the jerkiness still happens which leads me to believe there might be an issue with the PositionEvaluation from SplineContainer.

Please refer to this uploaded video:
https://streamable.com/s5g52m

In the video, I used a simple straight spline with SplineAnimates, parented the camera, and offset the movement speeds. You will clearly see the racers that fall behind start to jerk erratically. I then disable the splineAnimates and implemented an incredibly simple movement script with offsets again, and you can see there is no jerky movement.

If anyone knows how to tackle this issue or point out mistakes from my end that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Martin.